# Is there a way to export/import Jupyter Notebook extensions?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm really enjoying the Unofficial Jupyter Notebook extensions [found here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There's the [Jupyter nbextensions configurator](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator) capability that allows one to interactive enable/disable extensions as well.

However, what do I do if I want to migrate to a new virtual environment? Is there a more seamless way of getting to my original configuration, other than manually executing `jupyter nbextension enable [extension]` for each one? Is there a way to export and import the extensions and settings?

Comment: You could install the two virtual environments as different kernels in jupyter: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments that way you only install jupyter and it's extensions once and then choose your venv as a kernel from within jupyter.

Comment: Ah. You're right. I've been looking at it the wrong way. Better to install interpreters into a single Jupyter than install Jupyter into every interpreter via pip. I'll take this as the accepted answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the two virtual environments as different kernels in jupyter: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments that way you only install jupyter and it's extensions once and then choose your venv as a kernel from within jupyter.

Another option is to use docker, which would allow you to commit the environment to source control (i.e. it will be easier to share).